# Inline edit of the Title

Tags: title

Does anyone has real example of inline editing of the Title ? Pretty much in my case I have title of the current page and input fields below it etc. But since I have to name the current page that I am editing/creating and input field is not real solution I was thinking making the title with bigger font and to edit is somehow. Anyone has any real world examples ?

Answer (score 1):

On top of my head: Google Slides/Sheets, Miro

It's a good pattern for cases where you have a read-only AND editable content on the page, or if there's autosave.

However, if this is for explicit edit mode (has SAVE / CANCEL actions) then some might misread it as static text, so perhaps have it as label+input in the body.